# Javascript, problem with binding an event to a div-tag

Tags: javascript, function, html, prototype, onclick

i am trying to bind an event to a dynamically created div.

```
function GameField(playerNumber) {
this.fields = new Array();
this.player = playerNumber;
this.isPlayerActive = false;
this.currentRound = 0;
}

GameField.prototype.InitField = function(fieldNumber) {
    var newField = document.createElement("div");
    if (fieldNumber == 0 || fieldNumber == 6 || fieldNumber == 8 || fieldNumber == 17)
        newField.className = 'gameCellSmall borderFull gameText gameTextAlign';
    else
        newField.className = 'gameCellSmall borderWithoutTop gameText gameTextAlign';
    newField.onclick = function() { this.DivClick('a'); }
    this.fields[fieldNumber] = newField;
    return newField;
}

GameField.prototype.DivClick = function(fieldNumber) {
    alert('Nummer: ' + fieldNumber);
}
```

Everything works perfectly, but when you click on one of the created divs, i end up with the following error message: Error: Object doesn't support this property or method.

If i replace the onclick function with this, then it works:

```
newField.onclick = function() { alert('Nummer: ' + fieldNumber); }
```

How can i get the onclick event to fire my DivClick function instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `onclick` event handler gets executed with the `this` value pointing to the DOM element that triggered the event, so that's why executing `this.DivClick` fails.

You need to enforce the context, in order to use instance methods within the event handler, for example, you could store a reference to the current instance:

```
GameField.prototype.InitField = function(fieldNumber) {
    var newField = document.createElement("div");
    //...
    var instance = this;
    newField.onclick = function() { instance.DivClick('a'); }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the way

```
function DivClick (fieldNumber) {
        alert('Nummer: ' + fieldNumber);
    }
```

{ this.DivClick('a'); } - should be replaced to { DivClick('a'); }